# Getting session not found errors in Selenium 2 for certain browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm sorry if this question is vague, but I have a set of Selenium WebDriver tests, and they are currently not working in Chrome or IE. For whatever reason Firefox works fine.

The error is very similar for both Chrome and IE, and it is perplexing because I know for sure that the Chrome tests have worked before.

(And yes, I do have chromedriver in the path and it is opening the browser).

Basically what happens is that the tests will run partway through and are even able to interact with the page.

Eventually, though, they all fail with this error:

```
     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 

     session 2fca1234-343f-45e7-af49-6486b13e1eba does not exist
```

I was just wondering if anyone else has seen this error or anything similar.

I have looked around quite a bit and haven't found anyone having the same issue.

For the record, I am running my tests in Java and using Selenium 2.5

Answer (score 3):

I've been seeing the `Session not found` error in my Chrome automation. By examining the logs from these failures, I've determined that the error occurs because the `DELETE session` command is sent twice at the end of the test. The first `DELETE` actually deletes the session, so the second `DELETE` has no session to talk to.

I haven't dug into the Selenium `WebDriver` code enough to figure out why `DELETE session` is sent twice.

Answer (score 1):

I am using webdriver c# combination to automate my web based application, I normally get that error when I do webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL); and the URL string given doesn't opens any webpage

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `driver.close()` with `driver.quit()` for IE.

This helped me. I was getting a similar error when I was using `driver.close()` with IE while was working fine with both Chrome & FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens it means that you have closed the old session of the web driver. Create a new instance of the webdriver. 
Ie: for C#

```
var wdriver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver();
```